# Помогите исправить ошибку программе

Tags: c++

Задание:

> Дан текст. Словом текста считается любая последовательность цифр;
>   между соседними словами - не менее одного пробела. Перед первым и за
>   последним словом каждой строки произвольное число пробелов. Найти и
>   сохранить в каждой строке только те слова, которые образованы
>   неубывающей последовательностью символов.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"russian");
    ifstream file;
    file.open("text.txt");
    string line, word;
    ostringstream outline;


    cout << "Файл до обработки: " << endl;
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        cout << line << endl;
        istringstream iss(line);

        while (iss >> word)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
            {
                if (word[i] < word[i+1] )
                {
                    outline << word<<' ';
                }
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    cout << endl << "Файл после обработки:" << endl;
    cout << outline.str();

    file.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Проблема в том, что проверяются только 2 символа слова, а не все.

Преподаватель сказал, что лучше использовать флаги.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос входные данные и что ожидается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вы же тут не даете циклу даже шанса на вторую итерацию своим `break`. Правда, это спасает вас от выхода за границы слова при `i == word.size()-1`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
{
    if (word[i] < word[i+1] )
    {
        outline << word<<' ';
    }
    break;
}
```

Я бы делал примерно так (не компилировал, чисто как намек):

```
bool ok = true;
for (int i = 0; i < word.size()-1; i++)
{
    if (!isdigit(word[i]) || word[i] >= word[i+1])
    { 
        ok = false; break; 
    }
}
if (ok) cout << word << endl;
```